# What is easiest way to convert backticks into '<code>' and '</code>'?

Tags: php, regex

What is the easiest way to make this PHP function so that every other **backtick** becomes a beginning and ending **HTML tag**, so that:

```
'in for loops, use `$index` for 0-n values and `$count` for 1-n values'
```

becomes:

```
'in for loops, use <code>$index</code> for 0-n values and <code>$count</code> for 1-n values'
```

e.g.

```
$line = 'in for loops, use `$index` for 0-n values and `$count` for 1-n values';
echo getFormattedLine($line);

function getFormattedLine($line) {
    return $line; //...str_replace, regular expressions, etc.
}
```

Comment: You have 18k rep but it's only now you come into contact with regular expressions?

Comment: @CraigWhite - I have 9K and I'm still shy when it comes to regexs...

Comment: Is really the points someone has to say how he's good with this or that technology/language?

Comment: I found this tool: http://gskinner.com/RegExr/ absolutely invaluable when I needed to learn regular expressions. It's a really easy to use instant sandbox that has help tooltips, samples, error reporting etc.

Comment: I need to get a project done, it would have taken me 5-20 minutes to get back into regexes enough to figure that out, it took me 2 two minutes to write the question, Tomalak 1 minute to answer it, he gets points, I get my code and move on, and the question gets in google for stackoverflow, not everyone here is a full-time developer and we appreciate the help of people who are

Comment: Whilst I appreciate the practicality, Edward, strictly speaking I think this question is far too localised for SO. We're not here to cover every super-specific use case. I didn't really think about that before answering, but there we go. (Also, quit abusing commas! :D)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Seems pretty trivial:

```
preg_replace('/`(.*?)`/', '<code>$1</code>', $str);
```